# Is any of these two groups a smooth manifold?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

This question came to my mind while I was going through Iian B. Smythe's talk titled [A Crash Course in Topological Groups](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~ismythe/Olivetti_Nov_2011_slides.pdf).

In the talk it is mentioned that,

> Lie group G is a group, which is also a smooth manifold

My question is:

1. Is the automorphism group of a graph, $A$, a smooth manifold?
2. Is the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ a smooth manifold?

My effort:
I understand that I have to [prove the following](http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/math534_1011/Chap1.pdf).

1. $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are Hausdorff
2. $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are second countable
3. $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are locally Euclidean
4. Somehow I have to prove that they are differentiable.

Could anyone help me to at least start?

Comment: This should all be rephrased as "can be given the structure of a Lie group", as opposed to having that from the start. In this case, your groups are countable sets which naturally should have the discrete topology. They form a 0-dimensional smooth manifold, where the smooth structure is stupid (every map out of them is smooth).

Comment: Right, so these are not in any natural way "interesting" smooth manifolds (by which I mean at least positive-dimensional).

Comment: @MikeMiller, are these two groups then topological groups?

Comment: Again, that's added structure. If I give you a set with a multiplication operation that satisfies the operation of a group, it's not possible to say "This is a topological group". A topological group is a group with *further structure*: a set *with a topology* and a group multiplication such that multiplication and inversion maps are both continuous. Then a Lie group is further extra structure beyond this. The groups you're thinking of here  are either finite or countable, and I would probably want to give them a discrete topology. (If they're finite, this is the only Hausdorff topology.)